# I can no longer access any other content now that I've done some data binding to mainpage.xaml

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, maui, wordle-game

I'm kind of new to .net maui and c# in general and im trying to program a wordle game and a problem ive encountered is when using databinding on my main page a few problems have arisen:

The main page is the only page you can access when the program runs, like the app is literally locked on it
The button i have to navigate away from the page no longer works its just there
And the function I have to get a random word out of a long list from github no longer fires. Im using the community toolkit and I should have all the correct stuff for it to work properly

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Wordle.MainPage"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Wordle.ViewModel"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Wordle.Models"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:WordleViewModel"
             Title="Welcome to Wordle">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="30"
            Padding="20"
            VerticalOptions="Center">
            
            <!--Content of our main page-->
            <Image Source="gametitle.png"
                   HeightRequest="150"/>
            
            <Grid RowDefinitions="*, Auto">
                <VerticalStackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentRow}">
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:GameRows">
                            <HorizontalStackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding CorrectLetters}"
                                                   HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Letters">
                                        <Button Style="{DynamicResource LettersColor}"
                                                Text="Test"
                                                BackgroundColor="{Binding bgCol}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            </HorizontalStackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </Grid>
            <Button x:Name="signInbtn" Text="?" Clicked="signIn"
                    WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Gray" TextColor="White"/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Microsoft.Maui.Storage;
using Wordle.ViewModel;

namespace Wordle
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        //Declaring Variables
        private Random rand;
        private List<string> gameWords;
        private HttpClient http;
        private string userGuess;
        private string correctWord;
        private int gamesPlayed;
        private int numWords;
        public string userName;
        private string password;
        public string targetFile;
        public bool isBusy;
        public MainPage(WordleViewModel newView)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = newView;
            gameWords = new List<string>();
            rand = new Random();
            numWords = gameWords.Count;
            Task task = getGameWords();
            DisplayAlert("Test", correctWord, "Okay");
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new WordleViewModel();
            gameWords = new List<string>();
            rand = new Random();
            numWords = gameWords.Count;
            Task task = getGameWords();
            DisplayAlert("Test", correctWord, "Okay");
        }

        public async Task getGameWords()
        {
            targetFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, "words.txt");
            if (!File.Exists(targetFile))
            {
                http = new HttpClient();
                var response = await http.GetAsync("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DonH-ITS/jsonfiles/main/words.txt");

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(targetFile))
                    {
                        writer.Write(contents);
                    }

                    using (StreamReader s = new StreamReader(targetFile))
                    {
                        string line = "";
                        while ((line = s.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            gameWords.Add(line);
                            Console.WriteLine(line);
                            numWords++;
                        }
                    }
                    getRandWord();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (StreamReader s = new StreamReader(targetFile))
                {
                    string line = "";
                    while ((line = s.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        gameWords.Add(line);
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                        numWords++;
                    }
                }
                getRandWord();
            }
        }

        public void getRandWord()
        {
            rand = new Random();
            correctWord = gameWords[rand.Next(gameWords.Count)];

        }
        private void signIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new SignIn());
        }

        
    }

}
```

```
//This is the viewModel im using
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using Wordle.Models;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;

namespace Wordle.ViewModel
{
    public partial class WordleViewModel: ObservableObject
    {
        //Declaring Variables
        [ObservableProperty]
        public GameRows[] currentRow;
        private int currentRowIndex;
        private int currentColumnIndex;
        char[] answer;
        char[] userGuess;

        //Constructor to initialize some of the aspects of the ViewModel
        public WordleViewModel()
        {
            currentRow = new GameRows[6]
            {
                new GameRows(),
                new GameRows(),
                new GameRows(),
                new GameRows(),
                new GameRows(),
                new GameRows()
            };
            //Testing storing the correct answer
            answer = "tests".ToCharArray();
        }

        //Getting the user to the next time every time they hit enter
        //[ICommand]
        public void nextLine()
        {
            //Controlling when to move the user to the next row
            var isValid = true;
            if(isValid)
            {
                if(currentColumnIndex != 5)
                {
                    return;
                }

                if(currentRowIndex == 5)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    currentRowIndex++;
                    currentColumnIndex = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        //[ICommand]
        public void userEntry()
        {
            if(currentColumnIndex == 5)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
//This is the model im using
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace Wordle.Models
{
    public class GameRows
    {
        //Declaring Variables
        int currentRow;
        int currentCol;
        char[] answer;
        char[] userGuess;

        //Constructor to initialize some of the variables of the Model class
        public GameRows()
        {
            CorrectLetters = new Letters[5]
            {
                new Letters(),
                new Letters(),
                new Letters(),
                new Letters(),
                new Letters(),
            };
        }

        //Correct Letters
        public Letters[] CorrectLetters { get; set; }
        public void ValidateAnswer(char[] correctWord)
        {

        }
        
    }
    public partial class Letters : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private char userInput;
        [ObservableProperty]
        private Color colorChange;
        public char CorrectLetter { get; set; }
        public Color bgCol { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the relevant code.  The XAML is not enough to determine what you're doing wrong.  The `Button` inside the `DataTemplate` does not have clicked hadler or Command assigned, so it will do nothing when pressed.  The other button should fire the `signIn` method in the code behind

Comment: When you click the signin button does your event handler get called?  What happens when you step through that code?

Comment: Nothing at all, the name on the clicked event is correct and it worked previously but now its like the button has been disabled or something

Comment: have you actually verified that it is not being called using the debugger?

Comment: No, how do i do that

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp

Comment: Does SignIn page (I assume it's a page, right?) constructor get called? Click on the line number on the left in your IDE and set a breakpoint to check that.

Comment: I think the problem is that something is now locking me from performing any actions, I have a keyboard created and the buttons for that arent working either. Im following along with a guide by james montemagno. I have a github created for this and i can link to the repository if that would help explain things better?

Comment: @Eoin Yes, please post your github link.

Comment: https://github.com/eoinocathasaigh/Wordle

Comment: I ran your project. After the project is started, project will display the WelcomePage. Clicking the PlayWordle button in the page will enter the MainPage. Clicking the “?” button on the MainPage will enter the SignInpage. Is your problem that you cannot jump between pages normally?

Comment: Oh thats strange? My problem is that once the project starts it displays the MainPage and whereas it should display the WelcomePage and function like it did for you. Perhaps the problem is with something on my end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that your code in the `App.xaml.cs` file is different from mine. Setting `WelcomePage` to `MainPage` will cause the project to only display the `WelcomePage` page.

Since you used the [Shell architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/?view=net-maui-8.0) in the project, you can try setting `AppShell` to `Mainpage` in App.xaml.cs file like the following code.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new AppShell();
    }
}
```

Comment: That managed to get it working, thank you